# is mongo find syntax for "exact embeded document match" ambigious with "implicit and"?

Tags: mongodb, parsing, syntax, nosql

For me it looks like there is some ambiguity in mongo query syntax or I am missing something. I think second one is more likely, if so, let me know where I am mistaken.

from mongo docs:

> Specify Equality Condition.
>   To specify equality conditions, use `<field>:<value>` expressions in the query filter document: 
>   `{ <field1>: <value1>, ... }` The following example selects from the inventory collection all >documents where the status equals "D":
>
> `db.inventory.find( { status: "D" } )`

so `{status: "D", title: "sometitle"}` finds documents with both status="D" and title="sometitle" at the same time, because there is implicit "and" operator between entries in this object.

on the other hand again from docs:

> For example, the following query selects all documents where the field
>   size equals the document `{ h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }`:
>
> `db.inventory.find( { size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" } } )`

so this is performing equality operator on value of size (nested document) and given document.

and the syntax look pretty similar to me, except one is querying nested document and other one top level document. what would this query select:

`{address: {street: "abc", city: "somecity"}}`

is it equal to:
`address == {street: "abc", city: "somecity"}`
or
`"address.street" =="abc" and "adress.city=="somecity" (but there might exists other fields like "zipcode"`

what is the rule of thumb when determining, when one is parsing the query, if dictionary (map/object) is exact value or is a bunch of equality operators combined with "and"?